# Why spectral radius $\rho\left(A\right) > 0$ for $A \geq 0$ with $A^k > 0$ for positive integer $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why does spectral radius $\rho\left(A\right) > 0$ for a non-negative matrix $A \in M_n$, i.e., $A \geq 0$ with $A^k > 0$ for some positive integer $k$?

I guess it is related to Perron-Frobenius theorem? right? if yes, do we have a short and simple proof for non-experts like me?

Thank you very much

Comment: The only way $\rho(A) > 0$ fails to hold is if $\rho(A) = 0$, in which case all eigenvalues of $A$ are zero. But if $A$ satisfies $A \succeq 0$ and $A^k \succ 0$ for some $k$, then I think there must be a positive eigenvector. [I may be wrong.]

Comment: Indeed, this is just one of the statements in the Perron-Frobenius theorem for primitive matrices, see, e.g. [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is nonnegative, so it has a nonnegative eigenvector $v$ for the eigenvalue $\rho(A)$ and in turn, $A^kv=\rho(A)^kv$. Since $A^k>0$ and $v$ is nonnegative but nonzero, the product $A^kv$ is positive. Therefore the equality $A^kv=\rho(A)^kv$ implies that $\rho(A)>0$ **and** $v>0$.

As pointed out in a comment, this result is also regarded as part of Perron-Frobenius theorem for primitive matrices.

Comment: Doesn't "$A$ is nonnegative, so it has a *nonnegative* eigenvector $v$ for the eigenvalue $\rho(A)$" need justification, or am I missing something?

Comment: @angryavian That's Perron-Frobenius theorem for nonnegative matrices. Although most proofs of Perron-Frobenius begin with an irreducible or positive matrix, It is possible to prove the theorem with nonnegative matrices first (such as Karlin's proof for positive operators on Banach space), then refine it for irreducible matrices, primitive matrices and finally positive matrices. So, the proof here isn't circular.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for the clarifications